# ¿Cómo obtener un dato en concreto que varía de una API? Python

Tags: python, api

Me gustaría saber como en Python obtener los datos de un fragmento de una línea de API que siempre cambia y no se puede predecir.

Un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

```
   "Valores": {
    "Valor.Ejemplo.Importante_relleno": "Resultado",
    "Valor.Ejemplo.TGFDvd_relleno": "Resultado2",
    "Valor.Ejemplo.T54TFV_relleno": "ResultadoX"
    }
```

De ahí es de donde quiero extraer, solo me interesa la zona donde se encuentra la palabra "Importante,TGFDvd y T54TFV" y no el resto, me gustaría que el resultado fuese lo siguiente en un archivo JSON.

```
Importante: Resultado.
TGFDvd: Resultado2.
T54TFV: ResultadoX
```

Como pueden observar solo necesito el texto de la zona del medio por lo que solo necesitaría algún tipo de función que desconozco para colocar ahí, si es que no me equivoco, gracias de antemano.

El código que tengo hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

```
def hotfix():
    try:
        with open('Cache/hotfix.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as file:
            Cached = json.load(file)
        data = requests.get(
            'URL de la API')
        new = data.json()
        if data.status_code != 200:
            return
    except:
        return
    if Cached["Valores"] != new["Valores"]:
        print("detectado")
        MODULES.post_text(get_text("hotfix") + new["Valor.Ejemplo.X_relleno"])
        with open('Cache/hotfix.json', 'w', encoding="utf8") as file:
            json.dump(new, file, indent=3)
```

En la parte de texto `new["Valor.Ejemplo.X_relleno"])` la X es la zona que cambia pero no sé como expresar.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Modifiqué la publicación añadiendo al final el trozo de código del que dispongo.